# one Main index.php for multiple pages/Folders

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

Is it possible to have a single index.php for the whole filetree?

Basically i have a folder/subPage on my website that allows filebrowsing.
since i might want  to change the look of the filebrowser i want to have a central index.php and have the other index.php's load the main php instead of beeing a copy of the original file.

(at the moment i have to coppy the index.php and the htaccess file in every sub folder)

what i want: a php file that loads the php file from the main folder

eg. 
/Files/Fileindex/index.php < the main php
/files/other/.index.php < the php that should load the main php

i hope i was detailed enougth for you to understand this...

btw: i am new to stackoverflow (finaly decided to make an account)

Comment: You can use simple php switch case program to do it

Answer (score 0):

I guess yes, but it related with using MVC pattern. Now you have multiple entry points, but mvc require single entry point and another behavior. So if you want it, you may have a look for MVC. But also for your case it might be hard move your application to completly another application structure, architecture and logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your .htaccess file in your base directory to have the following line: `ErrorDocument 404  /index.php`
This makes the application refer to the base index.php file when you refer to any file that is not there.
Do not copy this index.php file to other folders. So, if you refer to a index.php file from a child directory, you get the base index.php(as there is no index.php in the child directory)
 
Like this you can have a single catch-all index page.

Comment: i might should have mentioned that the server also runs Wordpress.  and i assume that would only work for a bare html / PHP site without wordpress

Answer (score 0):

You can use `switch - case` program. Follow the below example.

**index.php**

```
switch($_GET['pageid']) {

  default:
     include('index1.php');
  break;

  case 'index2':
        include('mainphp/files/other/index.php');
  break;

  case 'index3':
        include('mainphp/files/another/index.php');
  break;

  case 'index4':
        include('mainphp/files/about.php');
  break;

}
```

**index1.php**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">Call Main Index</a></li>
    <li><a href="?pageid=index2.php">Call Index2</a></li>
    <li><a href="?pageid=index3.php">Call Index3</a></li>
    <li><a href="?pageid=index4.php">Call Index4</a></li>
</ul>
```